# Error on trying to build an SFML example

Tags: c++, linux, debian, sfml

I'm a 'noob', so-to-speak, and I'm trying to put together this simple SFML window test on my 64-bit crunchbang linux laptop.

```
    #include <SFML/Window.hpp>

    int main()
    {
         // Create the main window
         sf::Window App(sf::VideoMode(800, 600, 32), "SFML Window");

         // Start main loop
         bool Running = true;
         while (Running)
         {
              App.Display();
         }

         return 0;
    }
```

So, that's the file I'm trying to compile and build.
This is what goes down when I take it to the console.

```
    drdeviation@521463:~/cpp/test1$ g++ -c window-window.cpp
    drdeviation@521463:~/cpp/test1$ g++ -o window-window.o -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/crt1.o: In function `_start':
    (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    drdeviation@521463:~/cpp/test1$
```

So, I really have no idea of what's causing this issue... I've been beating my brains out trying to solve this one problem. SOMEONE. HALP. My apologies, if it's something stupid I'm overlooking...

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
g++ -c window-window.cpp
g++ -o test window-window.o -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```

OR

```
g++ -o test window-window.cpp -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```